# Android Development: Can Video Output Format and Encoding be specified when using Existing Camera?

Tags: android, mobile, h.264, video-encoding

When developing an Android Application that uses an **Existing Camera App** to capture a video clip, can the **Video Output Format** and **Encoding** be specified/ forced?

*E.g.: Forcing H.264 encoding format over camera's default encoding format.*

As far as the Android API guide describes, there are only 4 extra information parameters that are supported.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents

> - **MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT** - This setting
>     requires a Uri specifying a path and file name where you'd like to
>     save the video. This setting is optional but strongly recommended. If
>     you do not specify this value, the Camera application saves the
>     requested video in the default location with a default name, specified
>     in the returned intent's Intent.getData() field.
> - **MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY** - This value can
>     be 0 for lowest quality and smallest file size or 1 for highest
>     quality and larger file size.
> - **MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT** - Set this value
>     to limit the length, in seconds, of the video being captured.
> - **MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT** - Set this value to
>     limit the file size, in bytes, of the video being captured.